# Retrieve calendar events based on eventguest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

How can I retrieve all the events from a calendar that have a specific email address in the Guest list, using advanced option parameter of [`getEvents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents%28Date,Date,Object%29) method?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `options` parameter of `getEvents()` provides no way to search the guest lists of events.

Here's a function that will return an event list containing only events that have the specified email address in the guest list. This function is also [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/5548177).

```
/**
 * Gets all events that occur within a given time range,
 * and that include the specified guest email in the
 * guest list.
 *
 * @param {Calendar} calen Calendar to search
 * @param {Date} start the start of the time range
 * @param {Date} end the end of the time range, non-inclusive
 * @param {String} guestEmail Guest email address to search for
 *
 * @return {CalendarEvent[]} the matching events
 */
function getEventsWithGuest(calen,start,end,guestEmail) {
  var events = calen.getEvents(start, end);
  var i = events.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (!events[i].getGuestByEmail(guestEmail)) {
      events.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return events;
}

// Test function
function test_getEventsWithGuest() {
  var calen = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var now = new Date();
  // then... four weeks from now
  var then = new Date(now.getTime() + (4 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  var events = getEventsWithGuest(calen,now,then,'guest@somewhere.com');

  Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);
}
```